# Issues with Sharing Saved Games Across Devices in Flutter App

Tags: android, flutter, authentication, google-cloud-platform, google-play-services

I'm currently working on a Flutter app where I'm using the [games_services package](https://pub.dev/packages/games_services)  to implement the "Saved Games" feature. I've encountered an interesting behavior that I can't quite figure out, and I'm seeking some assistance.

When I install the app from the Google Play Store on two different devices (let's call them Device A and Device B), everything works as expected – both devices can see and access each other's saved games. However, if I install the same app directly using `flutter run` on both devices, the synchronization of saved games doesn't seem to work. In this case, Device A cannot see the saved games of Device B and vice versa.

Has anyone experienced a similar issue or have any idea what might be causing this and how I can resolve it? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Following online tutorials, I have done the following:

- Deployed the app in the Play Store and set it up as a project in the Google Cloud Console.
- Entered the SHA-1 fingerprint of the certificate issued by Google in the Cloud Console.
- Using Log-Cat, I noticed that the app, when started with `flutter run`, uses the fingerprint of the upload certificate for accessing the Games Services. However, when the app is installed from the Play Store, the fingerprint of the Google certificate is used. To accommodate both scenarios, I created another project in the Google Cloud Console with the same package name and the fingerprint of the upload certificate. Now, I can use the Games Services both when starting the app with `flutter run` and when installing it from the Play Store.
- I have set up test users in both the Developer Console and the Google Cloud Console.
- The app has been released for internal testing.